# Windows 8 won't go into standby - screen turns off, fans stay on

Tags: windows-8, suspend, standby

For the past 6 months, my computer has been refusing to go into standby mode (S3, "Suspend-to-Ram") - at least *sometimes*. On average 2 out of 3 times suspending is working as intended.

Upon trying to enter standby mode, you can hear my hard disks spinning down, my sound card shutting down (distinct clicking sound) and the screen turns off - however, the case fans will stay on infinitely (tested for 15+ mins). The only way to "resume" is to completely power-off my computer and boot again.

My hardware specs:

- Asus P8Z68-V Pro/Gen3 (Bios Version 3603), i5-2500K, 16GB RAM

  - JMicron 36X eSATA
  - Intel Gigabit NIC 82579V
- Samsung 840 Pro SSD, 2*1TB Samsung HDD
- ASUS Geforce GTX 660TI
- ASUS Xonar Essence STX

Disabling things like Wake-on-Lan and wake via USB did not help, neither did I get any pointers by running `powercfg -energy`. I also disabled everything related to Windows Media sharing and tried both disabling and enabling hibernate.

My drivers are all up-to-date, as are the firmware of my SSD and the BIOS of my GPU.

What irks me the most is the fact that this has worked flawlessly for at least a year, both on Windows 7 and 8. However, even completely starting from scratch and reinstalling Windows just this week did not fix the issue for me.

Is there any way to diagnose standby problems like mine further?

Comment: Have you tried looking in the device manager for any devices that are "allowed to wake this computer"?

Comment: Yes, but it did not help. To contribute something useful, the command `powercfg -devicequery wake_armed` is extremely convenient and shows which devices are currently allowed to wake your computer.

Comment: Probably not the answer but does is your motherboard on the Win 8 HCL... I'm wondering if Win 8 can't set your motherboard into a standby state through ACPI

Comment: Yes, my motherboard is on the HCL, and standby is working fine, just not every single time. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Do you remeber what changes you made before "6 months"? probably that can help to narrow down, any new devices installed etc.

Answer (score 0):

i remember the same issue

first of all check your installed programs there are some programs out there that prevent system from going to sleep (like virtual machines) try to close all open programs  and then sleep it

one of my friend had the same issue and i push her a file that you can use its comment into run and test it (http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/555569

1]Make sure that the system is hibernation disabled. To confirm that, Click the Start button, go to Run menu and type in Powercfg.cpl  and click OK. In the Power Options Propertiesclick Hibernate  tab and make sure that Enable hibernation option is unchecked. Click OK/Apply.

2]Now Click the Start button, go to Run menu and type in %windir%\System32\rundll32.exe powrprof.dll,SetSuspendState and click OK.)

for the last check try to re install your graphics cards 
(i do not have 50 repetition to comment so don't vote me up please thanks)